# Single page site (Wordpress) including posts

Tags: loop

I'm creating a single page site and obviously want to include the blog posts. I'm currently looping through the pages and using the_content() and the_title() to display them. However, the_content doesn't include the blog posts on the blog page. I tried another loop in this one, but it didn't work. Any ideas to point me in the right direction? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To include posts and pages in the loop, use the 'post_type' argument:

```
<?php
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$args = array(
     'post_type' => array('post','page')
);
$wp_query->query($args);
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
?>

<?php the_content(); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: Ah didn't think to use post_type, thanks a bunch. I can definitely use this help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop_in_Action

```
if (have_posts()) :
  while (have_posts()) :
    the_post();
    the_content();
  endwhile;
endif;
```

More info: http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

If you want more help, post some code!